High-value insurance options for luggage lost or stolen during long-term bus travel in the US
I am planning a long-term bus trip in the United States, and I will be carrying luggage worth more than $1,000. I am looking for travel insurance that can cover the full value of my luggage in case it gets lost or stolen during the trip.
I have found some companies, such as Travel Insured, that offer coverage up to $1,000 for bus trips. However, I need coverage for a higher value.
Are there any insurance options available that can provide coverage for luggage valued at more than $1,000 during long-term bus travel in the US? If so, could you please provide some recommendations or point me in the right direction?
Thank you for your help!

A quick search threw up these options. If you have home contents insurance it might be possible to increase the ‘away from home personal possessions’ cover for an extra premium.

I would VERY carefully read the terms and conditions before paying for any insurance. Most T&Cs will include a lot of exclusions. You want to make sure the insurance actually cases that are not already covered by the travel provider. I don't think that any insurance will pay of you just lose your bags.

A lot of options will depend where you currently reside. Some health/travel insurances, credit card insurances, and home contents insurance might have cover for that, sometimes in the form of an add-on.

You might get better answers if you can say what the high value items are (expensive clothes, electronics, jewelry, etc). Some types of items might be excluded from some policies.
